# How to provide DRM/file security across an entire DFS?

Tags: read-only, drm, dfs

I can't seem to find an answer to this myself and have come across several barriers to trying to even get started on it.

The background is:

- I manage the systems and technologies used by 60 schools across 4 countries
- The number of unique classes we offer is roughly 1,000 per country, so the content includes 1,000 .PPT, .PDF, .DOC, .MP3, .SWF and/or .MP4 files (many classes contain extra reading material, movies and audio examples)
- We set the content schedule (which classes to teach each week) centrally, then each school schedules them according to the needs of their students. Right now each school uses Windows 7 and they must get the classes via FTP each week.
- Right now the files are password protected by their author, which, given human memories and company churn rates, is creating a lot of double work.

For this many files, to this many schools, this doesn't really work.

What I imagine is a scheduled/automated DFS system that lets us push the content to each school 3 weeks at a time (meaning teachers can teach this week and prepare 2 weeks in advance). At the same time, I'd like to include some network or file security that ensures the materials remain read-only and can't be copied off the network.

I have no idea how to get started on this, or if it's even possible. I don't even know what I should be considering, besides the obvious. I really welcome the advice and questions of anyone familiar with sort of thing!

Comment: This has been [asked](http://superuser.com/questions/406082/shared-folder-read-only-but-anti-copy) [many](http://superuser.com/questions/391876/can-i-encrypt-data-in-a-way-that-it-can-be-read-normally-but-cant-be-copied-or) [times](http://superuser.com/questions/484142/how-to-protect-copying-files-out-of-flash-memory) [before](http://superuser.com/questions/434849/cmd-prevent-user-copy-files-in-a-directory-to-somewhere-else). If a file can be read, it can be copied.

Comment: OK, thanks. These didn't come up when I was searching/composing the question. Still, this only addresses a fraction of the overall question. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: If you want to keep anyone (students, I guess) from accessing the files, you will need some kind of encryption (I guess you could give people flash drives with keyfiles instead of making them remember passwords...).